# Transferring vs Transferred

Tags: grammar, difference

Please tell me what would differ if I change **transferring** to **transferred** in the sentence below.

> **Despicable me 2 :** It looks like agent Wilde will be *transferring* to our Australian
>   branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If he's *transferred*, then someone else is transferring him.

If he's *transferring*, nothing is said about whether it's his choice or someone else's.

Comment: Ah thank you very much. I thought transfer always means that something or someone is carried by others.

Comment: When a *person* is transferred, it almost always means that they get a new work assignment at a new location.  (The location may be just a shift within their organizational structure, for example from the Sales department to the Support department; or it may be a geographical location, for example from US Sales to Australia Sales.)

Answer (score 1):

To add to snail's answer, you would use "transferring" if you wanted to discuss the transferring as a process that would take a period of time, maybe to discuss things that you wanted to happen as part of that process.  "Transferred" implies that you are thinking about the transfer from the perspective of the future, when the transfer is fully complete, not thinking of it as a process that spans some time.

But they are very, very similar to each other, there are only the smallest shades of difference between the two words there.